# Embedding Examples & Solutions In Worksheets

Tags: exercises, exsheets

How can I "embed" examples and solutions into my code to make easy-to-use worksheets and solutions manuals?

Context: I am creating a fractions workbook for students, many of whom have many unfortunate challenges in life, so the workbook must be **uber** easy to use. This means the solutions manual needs to look *exactly* like the worksheets, except with answers in them. I am struggling to make this happen to the point where I'm not sure even how to make a decent MWE.

Below are links to my attempted MWE and a PDF of what I want. There is a large gap to close!

(If this thread needs to be broken down into smaller bits, just let me know and I'll do that.)

Any suggestions?

[How I want it to look, edited with pen](https://www.dropbox.com/s/wtfkjdf5wjwmuoq/how%20it%20should%20look.pdf?dl=0)

[image]

[My MWE of LaTeX code](https://www.overleaf.com/read/nwszdscqcpmy)

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{exsheets}
\usepackage{tikz}

% underline/answer space macro
\newlength{\ALT} %Sets name new my length, where ALT = Answer Line Thickness
\setlength{\ALT}{0.5pt} %sets thickness of that line
\newlength{\DLL} % DLL = default line length; that is if I don't otherwise specify the line length, it will be as long as I set it to here.
\setlength{\DLL}{0.8cm}
\newcommand{\AS}[1][\DLL]{\rule{#1}{\ALT}}

\begin{document}

\section{Worksheet Now}
Find the unknown.

\begin{question}
\(3+\AS=4\)
\end{question}

\begin{solution}
\(1\)
\end{solution}

\begin{question}
\(4=\AS-10\)
\end{question}

\begin{solution}
\(14\)
\end{solution}

\noindent
Shade the indicated length starting at zero.
\begin{question}
\(\frac{2}{5}\)

\tikz[xscale=2]
{
 % X axes
 \draw [line width =1pt]
  (0,0)--(3,0)
  (0,.5)--(3,0.5);
 % Vertical tick marks and answer boxes
 \foreach \x in {0,...,15}
  \draw [line width=1pt](\x/5,-0.4)--(\x/5,0.5);
 % Whole Number Labels
 \foreach \x in {0,1,2,3}
  \node[below] at (\x,-0.6) {\x};
}
\end{question}

\begin{solution}
\(\frac{5}{3}\)

\tikz[xscale=2]
{
 % Shaded bar length
 \filldraw[gray] (0,0) rectangle ({2/5},0.5);
 % X axes
 \draw [line width =1pt]
  (0,0)--(3,0)
  (0,.5)--(3,0.5);
 % Vertical tick marks and answer boxes
 \foreach \x in {0,...,15}
  \draw [line width=1pt](\x/5,-0.4)--(\x/5,0.5);
 % Whole Number Labels
 \foreach \x in {0,1,2,3}
  \node[below] at (\x,-0.6) {\x};
}
\end{solution}

\begin{question}
\(\frac{5}{3}\)

\tikz[xscale=1.5]
{
 % X axes
 \draw [line width =1pt]
  (0,0)--(3,0)
  (0,.5)--(3,0.5);
 % Vertical tick marks and answer boxes
 \foreach \x in {0,...,9}
  \draw [line width=1pt](\x/3,-0.4)--(\x/3,0.5);
 % Whole Number Labels
 \foreach \x in {0,1,2,3}
  \node[below] at (\x,-0.6) {\x};
}
\end{question}

\begin{solution}
\(\frac{5}{3}\)
\tikz[xscale=1.5]{
 % Shaded bar length
 \filldraw[gray] (0,0) rectangle ({5/3},0.5);
 % X axes
 \draw [line width =1pt]
  (0,0)--(3,0)
  (0,.5)--(3,0.5);
 % Vertical tick marks and answer boxes
 \foreach \x in {0,...,9}
  \draw [line width=1pt](\x/3,-0.4)--(\x/3,0.5);
 % Whole Number Labels
 \foreach \x in {0,1,2,3}
  \node[below] at (\x,-0.6) {\x};
}
\end{solution}

\pagebreak
\section{Solutions Now}
\printsolutions

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please edit your question and add your MWE there, instead of linking to it.

Comment: @Jubobs. Ok, but it's a little long...

Comment: Please upload the image showing how you want it to look here as well. I get a blank page with just Dropbox's header and footer when I follow your link. There's a Download button but clicking it does zilch for me.

Comment: @cfr I added the image :)

Comment: There is the `\blank[]{}` command provided by the package?

Comment: Thanks @clemens. Don't know why I can't see it if you can ;).

Comment: @cfr `\blank` doesn't behave like the OP wants it :)

Comment: @clemens It is closer than the custom macros in the question, though. I just wondered why the OP had written the macros rather than trying to use `\blank`. I agree it doesn't behave as requested - but I wondered if there might be other background desiderata here, too.

Comment: @cfr I misread your comment so my reply didn't make sense (which is why I deleted it again)

Comment: @clemens Mine is gone, too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wouldn't use `exsheets`' `solution` environment unless you want the solutions printed *separately* from the exercises. Instead I'd use a conditional switch. For example `exsheets` provides

```
\PrintSolutionsTF{if answers are printed}{if answers are not printed}
\PrintSolutionsT{if answers are printed}
\PrintSolutionsF{if answers are not printed}
```

One could use them to define a macro

```
\newcommand\answer[1]{\PrintSolutionsTF{#1}{\phantom{#1}}}
```

This either prints the argument or the space the arguments needs. A bit more customization (color, underlined answer, space, … – uses the `xcolor` package):

```
\makeatletter
% a color for answers:
\colorlet{answercolor}{orange}

\newcommand\answer[1]{\PrintSolutionsTF{#1}{\phantom{#1}}}

\newlength\answerspace
\setlength\answerspace{2cm}

\newcommand\answerline[1]{%
  \ifmmode
    \answerline@math{#1}%
  \else
    \answerline@text{#1}%
  \fi
}

\newcommand*\answerline@text[1]{%
  \underline{\makebox[\answerspace][c]{\answer{\color{answercolor}#1}}}%
}
\newcommand\answerline@math[1]{\mathpalette\answer@line@math{#1}}
\newcommand\answer@line@math[2]{\answerline@text{$#1#2$}}
\makeatother
```

With an `lrbox` one could also define an environment for larger chunks of input.

So a complete example could be the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{exsheets,amsmath,tikz}

\makeatletter
% a color for answers:
\colorlet{answercolor}{orange}

\newcommand\answer[1]{\PrintSolutionsTF{#1}{\phantom{#1}}}

\newlength\answerspace
\setlength\answerspace{2cm}

\newcommand\answerline[1]{%
  \ifmmode
    \answerline@math{#1}%
  \else
    \answerline@text{#1}%
  \fi
}

\newcommand*\answerline@text[1]{%
  \underline{\makebox[\answerspace][c]{\answer{\color{answercolor}#1}}}%
}
\newcommand\answerline@math[1]{\mathpalette\answer@line@math{#1}}
\newcommand\answer@line@math[2]{\answerline@text{$#1#2$}}
\makeatother


% uncomment to get answers printed:
% \SetupExSheets{solution/print=true}

\begin{document}

\section*{Find the unknown.}
\begin{question}
  \( 3 + \answerline{1} = 4 \)
\end{question}
\begin{question}
  \( 4 =  \answerline{14} -10 \)
\end{question}

\section*{Shade the indicated length starting at zero.}
\begin{question}
  \(\frac{2}{5}\)

  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \PrintSolutionsT{ \fill[answercolor] (0,0) rectangle (1,.5) ; }
    \draw[step=5mm] (0,0) grid (7.5,.5) ;
    \foreach \x [evaluate=\x as \xpos using \x*2.5] in {0,...,3}
      { \draw (\xpos,0)--++(0,-.2) node[below] {\x} ; }
  \end{tikzpicture}      
\end{question}

\begin{question}
  \(\frac{5}{3}\)

  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \PrintSolutionsT{ \fill[answercolor] (0,0) rectangle (2.5,.5) ; }
    \draw[step=5mm] (0,0) grid (4.5,.5) ;
    \foreach \x [evaluate=\x as \xpos using \x*1.5] in {0,...,3}
      { \draw (\xpos,0)--++(0,-.2) node[below] {\x} ; }
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{question}

\end{document}
```

This gives

[image]

And with `\SetupExSheets{solution/print=true}`:

[image]

Comment: This looks fantastic! I was just out of town for the long weekend but will take a closer look at this soon. Thanks so much!

Comment: @WeCanLearnAnything glad if my answer helps :)

Comment: Ok, I've been going through the code for a bit now and would like to try to make sense of it. Am I allowed to create a new "answer" to this thread, copy your code, then put my comments in there to see if I understand?

Comment: That's not really how this site works. Maybe you can start a new thread to this respect over at http://latex-community.org/forum/ and leave me a comment here. A forum is much easier for discussions… we could also talk about this here in chat.

Comment: Ok, I'll try that.

Comment: Just posted here.   http://latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=44&t=26667